# Programming for Casio calculator

Tags: calculator

Want to create several programs for my Casio fx-9860GII, but it takes forever typing on the calculator keyboard. Are there any SDK for the casio that will allow me to type on my computer? 
I tried using the FX-9860G Manager PLUSS, but that doesn't allow me to export apps out of the emulator.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to search for something, and just came a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lZXbPKZ2vg showing how to transfer some games to your calculator...but, maybe it will enlighten you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The emulated device uses an SD-card (unlike my device). This enables me to transfer items from Main Memory to the SD card. Trying to do so lets me save the file on my computer. Which I can then transfer to my calculator with the FA-124 application.

Spent hours figuring all this out... horrible casio website(s).

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do it. You can compile C, C++ and ASM programs using the Casio SDK.
Which is also available on their website, they compile into an Add-in, and when you copy it using FA-124, it should show up on the menu.

Comment: This question brings back fond memories. Thank you for your reply, but my question was basically how to write programs using a keyboard, although I did (incorrectly) mention a SDK.